# Zookeeper connection timeout issues

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

We are using the 2.3.0 version of curator-framework to connect to connect to zookeeper in the pom file.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is used in the highly loaded server which pumps in data to kafka lot of times and we are getting the following errors every now and then. 
I tried googling but couldn't find the exact reason for the issue and the solution for it. Looking for ideas on how to solve this problem.

```
ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState: Connection timed out for connection string (xxx.xx.xx.xx:2181, yy.yy.y.y:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed (37893)
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:191)
        at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:86)
        at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:113)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:456)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:40)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:65)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:672)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:664)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:55)
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$3.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: Can you ping to the ip:port ?

Comment: Are you able to solve this one? Even I am facing similar issue during high loads.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adapt session and connection timeouts for your curator client. Check `connectionTimeoutMs` and `SessionTimeoutMs` settings for your `CuratorFramework`.

As a rule of thumb, your `connectionTimeoutMs` should be `SessionTimeoutMs` devided by number of Zookeeper nodes in the cluster. If client can't connect to one of the nodes withing `connectionTimeoutMs`, it will try to connect to another node, untill session times out.

Other settings to pay attention to are retry policy and interval between retries (if you use `RetryNTimes` policy, it worth to check that your `sleepBetweenRetries` is not too big and you get several retries within `connectionTimeoutMs` interval).